# "const std::string &msg" What, how and why? C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working through some SDL2 tutorials and I just got up to a part where you start building a error logger. The entire code is:

```
void logSDLError(std::ostream &os, const std::string &msg){
os << msg << " error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
}
```

After awhile I realized what "std::ostream &os" did but I don't understand why the & and the const are necessary with the string. Why are they required? I know that if I don't use them it throws an error. In case it's important this is a snippet of the code that would use this function:

```
if (loadedImage != nullptr){
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, loadedImage);
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    //Make sure converting went ok too
    if (texture == nullptr) logSDLError(std::cout, "CreateTextureFromSurface");
}
```

Comment: If by not using them, you mean `std::string msg`, that would compile fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your function header looks like this:

`void testfunction(std::string msg)`, and you call it, it will be created a copy of the string thus taking up more space. If you want to either save memory or use the actual memory location of the string, you should do:

```
void testfunction(std::string &msg);
```

Although, this is dangerous when you do not want to modify the string, that's why one should use

```
void testfunction(const std::string &msg);
```

when you do not want to use any additional space, but you don't want the string to editable in the function.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are they required?

The `const` and `&` are used to pass the string message by *constant reference* so that you can save a copy of the string. The reference is to avoid the copy, and the `const` is to prevent you from edit it.

> I know that if I don't use them it throws an error.

No, [it won't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aae590be966f24b) throw any error related to the function argument.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why the `&` and the `const` are necessary with the string.

`&` means you're passing by reference rather than value; `const` means the function can't use the reference to modify the string. Your introductory book should explain reference and value semantics in detail.

> I know that if I don't use them it throws an error.

You could remove both (or just `&`) and pass by value without error; but that might be less efficient since the string will typically have to be copied.

If you remove `const` but leave `&` (passing by non-constant reference) then you wouldn't be able to pass a temporary string to the function, as your example does. Temporaries can only be bound to constant references.